# Validation Summary working but Individual Validation Messages are Not working

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, validation, jquery-validate

Before I got into the details, this is what I have

Environment : VS 2008 with ASP.NET MVC 2

Base Model Code

```
    [DisplayName("Current Application Status")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Current Status has to be provided")]
    public virtual int CurrStatus{ get; set; }
```

Script References

```
    <link href="../../Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="../../Content/jqueryui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../../Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
    <script src="../../Scripts/jquery.validate.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
   <script src="../../Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

View Code

```
        <tr>
        <td><%= Html.LabelFor(model => model.CurrStatus) %></td>
        <td>
            <%= Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CurrStatus, Model.CurrentStatus, "-- Select Current Status --").ToString().Replace("CurrStatus", "Application.CurrStatus")%>
            <%=Html.ValidationMessageFor(model=>model.CurrStatus) %>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

Controller Code

```
        [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Prefix = "Application")] Application model)
    {
        try
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                     //save to db
            }
            else
            {
                InitSelectListItems();
                model.CurrentStatus = CurrentStatusModel.GetModelInstance().GetAllAsSelectListItems();
                return View(model);
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        catch
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

In the view, the validation summary is displaying the list of errors with the model that was submitted.  However the individual error messages is not shown for some reason. And to top this, I have enabled client side validation after adding entries into web.config and adding the jQUery scripts into scripts folder. The client side validation is not getting triggered either. Any help on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what you validation summary helper looks like but I can quess that you pass "true" value to the helper like that

> @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

This will exclude all properies erros from the summary according to MSDN:

> true to have the summary display model-level errors only, or false to
>   have the summary display all errors.

Could you please elaborate more on what exactly JQuery files you've added and what changes you've made to the web.config?

Didn't you forget to include the JQuery files into the application via bundles or script tag?

Comment: I tried adding the ValidationSummary to true. It hid the summary of errors that was displayed but it did not show the model level errors either. I am not sure I understand Validation Summary Helper. I do not have a custom extension for Validation Summary. I have included all the JQuery scripts tabs. I have udpated the jQuery part in original post.

Comment: This is the closest answer I got so I am accepting it. Thank you for your time.